# Adding quick replies to web chatbot using dialogflow (api.ai)

Tags: button, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I started to build a chatbot on my glitch server dealing with small talk questions using Dialog flow (api.ai).

I used the code, which i copy paste on the bottom (index.html). Now I want to add quick replies. This is very simple for integrated chatbots (e.g. in Facebook) but not for webchatbots, so my question is:

```
"How can I integrate quick replies (buttons) in this html code using dialogflow (api.ai)?"
```

So that the user gets buttons to choose instead of text as response?

Here my code (index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sara</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script   src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var accessToken = "cec56d4781974d09a2265e76a97f42fb",
  baseUrl = "https://api.api.ai/v1/",
  $speechInput,
  $recBtn,
  recognition,
  messageRecording = "Ich hör dir zu ...",
  messageCouldntHear = "I konnte dich nicht hören, kannst du das nochmals sagen?",
  messageInternalError = "Oh nein, es gab einen internen Server Fehler",
  messageSorry = "Tut mir leid. Ich kann das leider im Moment noch nicht verstehen.";

$(document).ready(function() {

  $speechInput = $("#speech");
  $recBtn = $("#rec");

  $speechInput.keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      send();
    }
  });
  $recBtn.on("click", function(event) {
    switchRecognition();
  });
  $(".debug__btn").on("click", function() {
    $(this).next().toggleClass("is-active");
    return false;
  });
});

function startRecognition() {
  recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
  recognition.continuous = false;
      recognition.interimResults = false;

  recognition.onstart = function(event) {
    respond(messageRecording);
    updateRec();
  };
  recognition.onresult = function(event) {
    recognition.onend = null;

    var text = "";
      for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
        text += event.results[i][0].transcript;
      }
      setInput(text);
    stopRecognition();
  };
  recognition.onend = function() {
    respond(messageCouldntHear);
    stopRecognition();
  };
  recognition.lang = "en-US";
  recognition.start();
}

function stopRecognition() {
  if (recognition) {
    recognition.stop();
    recognition = null;
  }
  updateRec();
}

function switchRecognition() {
  if (recognition) {
    stopRecognition();
  } else {
    startRecognition();
  }
}

function setInput(text) {
  $speechInput.val(text);
  send();
}

function updateRec() {
  $recBtn.text(recognition ? "Stop" : "Speak");
}

function send() {
  var text = $speechInput.val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: baseUrl + "query",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({query: text, lang: "en", sessionId: "yaydevdiner"}),

    success: function(data) {
      prepareResponse(data);
    },
    error: function() {
      respond(messageInternalError);
    }
  });
}

function prepareResponse(val) {
  var debugJSON = JSON.stringify(val, undefined, 2),
    spokenResponse = val.result.speech;

  respond(spokenResponse);
  debugRespond(debugJSON);
}

function debugRespond(val) {
  $("#response").text(val);
}

function respond(val) {
  if (val == "") {
    val = messageSorry;
  }

  if (val !== messageRecording) {
    var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    msg.voiceURI = "native";
    msg.text = val;
    msg.lang = "en-US";
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
  }

  $("#spokenResponse").addClass("is-active").find(".spoken-response__text").html(val);
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  background-color: #192837;
  font-family: "Titillium Web", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
input {
  background-color: #126077;
  border: 1px solid #3F7F93;
  color: #A6CAE6;
  font-family: "Titillium Web";
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 43px;
  padding: 0 0.75em;
  width: 400px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in;
}
textarea {
  background-color: #070F24;
  border: 1px solid #122435;
  color: #606B88;
  padding: 0.5em;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in;
}
input:active, input:focus, textarea:active, textarea:focus {
  outline: 1px solid #48788B;
}
.btn {
  background-color: #126178;
  border: 1px solid #549EAF;
  color: #549EAF;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Titillium Web";
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 43px;
  padding: 0 0.75em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in;
}
.btn:hover {
  background-color: #1888A9;
  color: #183035;
}
.debug {
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
}
.debug__content {
  font-size: 14px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in;
}
.debug__content.is-active {
  display: block;
  max-height: 500px;
}
.debug__btn {
  width: 100%;
}
.spoken-response {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in;
}
.spoken-response.is-active {
  max-height: 400px;
}
.spoken-response__text {
  background-color: #040E23;
  color: #7584A2;
  padding: 1em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<input id="speech" type="text">
<button id="rec" class="btn">Speak</button>
<div id="spokenResponse" class="spoken-response">
  <div class="spoken-response__text"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="debug">
<div class="debug__btn btn">
  Debug JSON results
</div>
<div class="debug__content">
  <textarea id="response" cols="40" rows="20"></textarea>
</div>
</div>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:200" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much for answering!!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do something like this:

```
function quickRepliesResponse(title, replies){
    var element ='<div class="chat-message clearfix">'+
                 '<div class="chat-message-content clearfix">'+
    element = element + 
                 '<p> '+ title +'</p>' ; 
    replies.forEach(function(replies) {
                    element = element +'<button class="butn butn-large" onClick="sendReply(\''+ replies + '\')">'+replies +'</button>';         
    });
    element = element +
                '</div>'+
                '</div> '+
                '<hr>';
    $(".chat-history").delay(2000).queue(function(next) {
        $(this).append(element);
        next();
});
}
```